# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

fout = open('words_list2.txt','w')

url = 'http://endic.naver.com/?sLn=kr'

doc = urlopen(url)

web_page = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

word = web_page.find(attrs={'class':"tit"})

definition = web_page.find(attrs={'class':"align_line"})

fout.write(word.get_text()+':'+ definition.get_text().replace('\u200b',''))

fout.close()
```

Comment: Why do you think you have a valid result in the previous line?

Comment: i don`t know what you mean...

Comment: Have you read your code?

Comment: yes. i just think that 'class':"tit" this type is not correct. so i want to know how to web crawling at this site

Comment: There are dozens of questions and answers with this exact or near exact error message. Please do a little research before asking a new question. If your question is truly unique, cite what research you've done and why the other answers aren't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

At the url http://endic.naver.com/?sLn=kr there's no element with the class `align_line` so `web_page.find(attrs={'class':"align_line"})` returns `None` and therefore `definition` is `None` and `definition.get_text()` isn't going to work